# c++ dependency injection and more complex structures

Tags: c++, object, vector, dependency-injection, instantiation

I'm trying to understand DI and separation of object construction and its logic, but I have problems with implementation in some cases. Here is the example.

```
class A
{
public:
    void load_bs(); // create some Bs and push them into bs_ vector
                    // and call load_cs on every created B
private:
    std::vector<B> bs_;
};

class B // does not need A reference for real work
{
public:
    void load_cs(); // create some Cs and push them into cs_ vector
private:
    std::vector<C> cs_;
};

class C // needs A and B
{
public:
    C(A &a, B &b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}

private:
    A &a_;
    B &b_;
};
```

How can I construct this structure according to DI? First I create instance of the A class, then call load_bs() method and create some B objects, so now it's time to create C objects in B instance. Since I should inject into the object only dependencies needed by this object, not only pass it through for use in another object, where I get reference to A inside B during C creation? Does it mean that C should be created somewhere else and passed into B?

When I inject dependency which is only injected into something else all I get is real hard refactoring when one of these dependencies should be removed or when I want to add new one available in object somewhere real high in hierarchy.

Comment: it is not about dependency injection, you just have circular dependencies, which usually means bad design

Comment: thx for reply, ok so I'll try to rework my design.

Comment: I think you want `void load_cs(A&);`.

Comment: Is that correct to inject A to method which ony inject it into another object?

Comment: It leads to the same problem, when some dependency of C must be changed. I have to refactor C, load_cs method and every place where it's used...

Comment: That's the point of my original question, where and how should I get references to objects. Lets say that C doesn't need A and B but some Foo and Bar objects (to fix circular dependency problem), where I get those dependencies when object where I construct C have no idea about Foo and Bar.